# how to download a pdf file stored in a server in client side in node.js server

Tags: node.js, pdf, mime-types

How to allow a client to download a pdf file stored in a server using node.js.

Please, someone help me out with this code.

```
fs.readFile('temp/xml/user/username.pdf',function(error,data){
    if(error){
       res.json({'status':'error',msg:err});
    }else{
       res.json({'status':'ok',msg:err,data:data});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Express has 2 convenience methods available for sending files. The difference being:

- [Simply sending the file](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile):

  ```
  res.sendfile('temp/xml/user/username.pdf');
  ```
- Or [with `Content-Disposition`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download) to suggest saving to disk:

  ```
  res.download('temp/sml/user/username.pdf');
  ```

Comment: +1 ahh he is using express. sigh, I don't know its methods and he didn't mention express anywhere.

Comment: What is 'res' and how to i get it?

Comment: @binaryBigInt `res` is an [Express Response](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) object, an extension of Node's own [ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) objects. It's provided by Express as an argument to [route handlers](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

Answer (score 5):

Send the correct [mime-type,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) and then the content of the pdf.

```
fs.readFile('temp/xml/user/username.pdf',function(error,data){
    if(error){
       res.json({'status':'error',msg:err});
    }else{
       res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
       res.write(data);
       res.end();       
    }
});
```

I'm assuming `res` is your response object.

---

Ah but you are using Express. Use Jonathan's answer instead.

Comment: I try both the code even is not working i am making the api call through ajax is that the matter.because the response of the ajax contain string data of the pdf file and i try to create blob builder to make blob data out of the response data and using FileSaver to save the file locally and the file got stored as empty there is no data in it(empty pdf stored). is there any other way to do this... help me ..