# how to read a pdf file using nodejs/expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

how to read a pdf file using nodejs ?
I have two issues:
1)I have a pdf file and i just want to read it and and display the contents in the browser.
2)Read and display the content of a specific page of file

Comment: you know the question is interesting But pls improve with something what have you tried where you can get more views and No Down votes

Answer (score 0):

If you want node to display a PDF file to a browser, you can simply have node send the PDF file upon HTTP request: `res.sendFile('./example/file.pdf');`
[This previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393166/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-stored-in-a-server-in-client-side-in-node-js-server) has more options and further details for sending PDF to the browser.

If you are trying to read (parse) the contents of the PDF, you can use [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json) to figure out what part of the PDF file you want to display.